# Как заполнить массив циклом

Tags: c#

Нужно заполнить массив таким образом(сформировать квадратную матрицу):

```
11111
22222
33333
44444
55555
```

Не могу сообразить как мне обратиться только к строке или только к столбцу.

Comment: https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level4/4_2.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать двумерный массив, тогда обращаетесь к конкретной ячейке:

```
var array1 = new int[,] { {1, 1 }, {2, 2} }; //Явное заполнение массива
var array2 = new int[2,2]; //массив пустой

var answer = array1[1,1]; //Ответ 2
```

В таком случае получается матрица произвольного размера.

Заполнить такой массив можно следующим образом:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayColumns; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < arrayRows; j++)
        array[i,j] = ...
```

Обратиться же к строке/столбцу нельзя, т.к. в памяти данные массива все равно расположены в одну строку, и обращаясь по индексу `[i, j]` вы по сути находите элемент номер j в последовательности под номером i

Пример:

Имея массив `var arr[3,3] = new int{{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}}` для машины он будет выглядеть так: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8`. Обратившись к элементу `[1, 2]` вы от самого первого символа отсчитаете 1*3 элементов(потому что длина каждой строки = 3), а затем еще 2 элемента и получите в ответе 4.

Comment: Так же есть такой способ создания многомерных массивов: `var arr = new int[length][]` - в ячейки такого массива можно добавить новые одномерные массивы, создав матрицу со строками разной длины